# IllegalStateException when creating new instances of @Scope("session")

Tags: spring

I used to have the following bean defined in XML (it worked!):

```
<bean id="session"  class="mrpomario.springcore.bean_scopes.beans.SessionBean" scope="session">
<aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

Now that I try to accomplish the same configuration through Java:

```
    @Bean
    @Scope("session")
    @ScopedProxy
    public SessionBean session() {
        return new SessionBean();
    }
```

I get the following error...

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope 'session'
```

...when I invoke `session()` as the argument of a setter in another bean.

Why does that happen and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@ScopedProxy` isn't part of Spring's Java configuraion. The solution is [in the reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-java-specifying-bean-scopehttp://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-java-specifying-bean-scopehttp://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-java-specifying-bean-scopehttp://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-java-specifying-bean-scopehttp://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-java-specifying-bean-scope) - use `proxyMode` of `@Scope` annotation:

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public SessionBean session() {
    return new SessionBean();
}
```