# Spring @Bean annotation differences (context vs config packages)?

Tags: spring

What is the difference between these classes and when should I use each in conjunction with @Configure?

org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean

org.springframework.config.java.annotation.Bean;

Comment: I believe that understanding this issue, I would also find the answer to another question of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289444/illegalstateexception-when-creating-new-instances-of-scopesession

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have an obsolete jar file in your classpath - `org.springframework.config.java.annotation.Bean` is no longer with the latest Spring 3.1.2 jars, it is the `org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean` annotation that should be used with the `@Configuration` classes

Comment: I have a limitation which is working with Spring 3.0. In that case, what should I do?

Comment: Oh, okay, I would suggest that you continue to use xml itself in that case, the reason is `@Configuration` has stabilized only with Spring 3.1.X

Comment: My limitation is working with JavaConfig on Spring 3.0. So, just so it is crystal clear to me. You are saying: 1) JavaConfig Spring 3.0, unstable, uses org.springframework.config.java.annotation.Bean 2) JavaConfig Spring 3.1, stable, uses org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean?

Comment: Yes, wouldn't put it as unstable with Spring 3.0, but would rather say that it needed to mature a little more the way it has with Spring 3.1.x

Answer (score 1):

The JavaConfig dependency is part of the `spring-context` as of Spring 3.0. Therefore if you are building your app using Spring > 3.0 use the [org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html)